# Can I use this air fryer basket with a non-stick coating as a grill basket?

Tags: grilling, cookware, barbecue, non-stick

**Scenario**

For (reasons), I have an extra inner basket for [this model](https://www.cosori.com/shop/cosori-premium-58-quart-air-fryer-cp158-af) of air fryer. I have completely removed the handle assembly; what I'm left with is a single piece of non-stick coated metal. I've been grilling a lot recently and experimenting with ways to cook different types of veggies on the grill I came across the concept of a 'grill basket'. I was wondering if I could use this air fryer basket on the grill. I use a Weber kettle charcoal grill and I'd have the basket on top of the grate, not directly in the coals.

The air fryer itself maxes out at 400 degrees Fahrenheit, but I couldn't find any information about the temperature rating of the actual basket or even specifics on the coating used.

**N.B.**

1. I couldn't find any good information about this online except for fairly common assertions that 'one shouldn't use non stick cookware at very high heats' without much in the way of specifics.
2. Looking through this stack I found [Why would a portable barbecue warn against using pots on the grill?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/why-would-a-portable-barbecue-warn-against-using-pots-on-the-grill) which actually didn't include any info on my topic and also [Cooking temperatures with non-stick cookwear](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/cooking-temperatures-with-non-stick-cookwear) which (surprisingly) didn't either.

**Question(s)**

1. What potentially deleterious effects might result from using this air fryer basket with a non stick coating on a charcoal grill?
2. Specifically what might be the possible negative outcomes from simply throwing some veg in there and trying it at least once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonstick vessels don't mix well with grills. First, it is likely to get overheated - I assume the basket is PTFE, which starts deteriorating at a little bit over 200 C (compatible with your fryer temp rating). Second, with grilling, you frequently have a situation where a tiny amount of oil (e.g. from a marinade) gets smeared on the rack (or basket, in this case) - that small amount then polymerizes in the heat and, on a nonstick surface, becomes a sad, useless version of cast iron seasoning.

If you really want to try grill baskets, search for a stainless steel solution, or try repurposing something else like a collander or steamer insert.

Also, note that we cannot answer your question on "definitely dangerous, probably safe, or something else". Any potential health effects (or lack of those) of overheated teflon are off topic on the site.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer on topicality for this stack - I've edited my question to reframe the ask, which may invalidate part of your answer as currently constituted - thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: While not the specific info I was looking for, this seems to be the correct - and is certainly the best - answer, so I've selected it. Again, I appreciate your effort in response.